# How to estimate the bias of linear cryptanalysis given the input and output masks

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, s-boxes, differential-analysis, linear-cryptanalysis

Assume the input linear mask is $a$, and output mask is $b$，for a block cipher $F$ with $r$ round,How to accurately and quickly estimate the bias of linear cryptanalysis? which is
\begin{equation*}
Prob\{a\cdot x+b\cdot F(x)=0 \}
\end{equation*}
is there any good algorithm？
Same question for differential cryptanalysis ,If the input differential is $a$ and output differential is $b$, how to calculate the probability of that
\begin{equation*}
Prob\{ F(x)+F(x+a)=b \}
\end{equation*}

Comment: http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf

Comment: One way to approximately estimate the linear bias is to find the minimum number of active sboxes and multiply it with linear bias probability of the sbox